# excel sum range with two index matched values with multiple occurence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUAG.png)

Hi I'm trying to get a sum of 59 for 2 criteria and multiple occurence.
See the picture. The problem with my current formula is that it only sums the first column mp1

the current formula is = SUMIFS(INDEX(B2:F9,,MATCH(I3,B10:F10,0)),A2:A9,I2) and give 4 as response instead of 59 (4+55).It stop at first column found.
Mp1 is found at b10 and e10
letter "D" is found at A5.
Now it must sum b5(4) +e5(55)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please post your current formula as it is always easier to improve something existing than to come up with it from scratch.

Comment: I think your formula is returning an array and will only show the first value. If you wrap a `SUM(your formula)` you should get 59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach where INDEX is used to return Cell Reference.

See below screenshot.

[image]

Formula in K5 is

```
=SUM(IF(D12:H12=K4,INDEX(D4:D11,MATCH(K3,C4:C11,0)):INDEX(H4:H11,MATCH(K3,C4:C11,0),0)))
```

This needs to be converted to an Array by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar. The formula will automatically enclose in curly braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula. This step is important.

Comment: Thank you I would never have been able to find it, I'm still trying to figure out how it works but it works on my worksheet